# Manifold/PostGIS data manipulation and export

Tags: postgresql, gis, postgis, manifold

I'm currently working on a GIS database project using Manifold Ultimate.
I am able to import data from PostGIS via the database console, and edit the data as a table object within Manifold.

1. How do i 'commit' these changes back to PostGIS?
2. I am required to submit the exported database. What format is expected for a PostGIS export and how is the exporting done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@mdsumner is correct. Linking the PostGIS data is the way to go.

If you have exported the complete table and edited records it's not simple to replace the data present in PostGIS by a new export. This will fail until you have deleted all the tables with index, triggers and sequences whose names are derived  from the same name of exported drawing (with inconsistend handling of lower case). It's not enought to drop the table.

Note that with Manifolds linked storage model you have no client buffer of edited, added or deleted records that are written back in a process of commitment of a transaction. Every edit of every single column is written to PostGIS at once.

Concerning your 2. question: That depends on the target system. Manifold exports GEOMETRY type geometries. Other PostGIS clients may digest only a single type point, line or polygon. You can edit the type in "geometry_columns.type" as long as you have added only the one type of object to the drawing.

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you imported the data it is no longer linked to the DB and you would need to export it and replace what is in the DB. If you link the data the edits you make are commited "live" as the data is not a copy but remains stored by the DB.

I'm not that familiar with this, but that's what the Database Console topic in help describes.